# Xcode error: "_main", referenced from: implicit entry/start for main executable

Tags: ios, xcode, clang

I am getting the following error, which seems to be coming from something in the bottom to do with "_main".

```
Ld /Users/jianglin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TownHall_iPhone-bdlgipvgaapgjhglhromfvcubbxz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TownHall\ iPhone.app/TownHall\ iPhone normal i386
    cd "/Users/jianglin/Desktop/TownHall iPhone"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/jianglin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TownHall_iPhone-bdlgipvgaapgjhglhromfvcubbxz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/jianglin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TownHall_iPhone-bdlgipvgaapgjhglhromfvcubbxz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/jianglin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TownHall_iPhone-bdlgipvgaapgjhglhromfvcubbxz/Build/Intermediates/TownHall\ iPhone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TownHall\ iPhone.build/Objects-normal/i386/TownHall\ iPhone.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lPods-AFNetworking -lPods-Masonry -lPods-SDWebImage -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework ImageIO -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/jianglin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TownHall_iPhone-bdlgipvgaapgjhglhromfvcubbxz/Build/Intermediates/TownHall\ iPhone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TownHall\ iPhone.build/Objects-normal/i386/TownHall\ iPhone_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/jianglin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TownHall_iPhone-bdlgipvgaapgjhglhromfvcubbxz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TownHall\ iPhone.app/TownHall\ iPhone

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_IVAR_$_PostTableViewCell._mainTextView, _OBJC_IVAR_$_ConfirmationViewController._mainLabel , _OBJC_IVAR_$_SignInViewController._mainLabel , _OBJC_IVAR_$_SignUpViewController._mainLabel )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I checked your project. The issue is simple, in your project there is no `main.m` file. I think you accidentally deleted that.

Add a new .m file to your project, name it as main

And add the following code to it:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Also in your project the info.plist is also missing, so you need to add a new one.

Comment: Thanks, I just forgot to add to target :\

Answer (score 3):

add @UIApplicationMain to the AppDelegate

Answer (score 1):

My case was very similar, but slightly different.  The solution was in part prompted by @Midhun-MP's answer above.

In my instance, I had added a tvOS version of my app.  After adding the new target however, main.m was not selected under Target Membership (thus, the warning messages about `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_main"`).  Checked that off and bam -- I'm GTG.

Thanks @Midhun-MP.

[image: main.m]

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, you are using simulator to run the application. For running app on iOSSimulator requires the support of i386 architecture. The error showing like one your binary framework for linking is not supporting i386 architecture. This may be the framework 'SDWebImage' (I guess). Please try to run the application in real device not simulator, or try to download the framework which has i386 entry points.

Another possibility is: verify the "AppDelegate" is existing in the compiled source. Hope this will help you ..

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, I am noticing that the libPods.a file is red, could this be affecting it? AppDelegate is there so should be ok. I do not have a working iphone to try without device simulator

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this after a large upgrade, and was quite annoying to see so many answers across Github advising RN users to start a new project to remedy this issue.

To start, here are the build settings I was mindful of when running into this error and the settings that should be set:

**Build Phases for the App Target**

***Link Binary With Libraries***

- JavaScriptCore.framework
- libPods-app_name.a

***Compile Sources***

- AppDelegate.m
- main.m

**Build Settings for App Target**

*Linking* OTHER_LDFLAGS

- ObjC
- lc++
- lz

*If the settings look fine, but you still receive the error on build, the next step is to check the main file itself.*

The *Main.m* file lives in the **ios/app_name** folder, and in the file itself, you will find the referenced main method. If there is an issue with this file (missing, broken), you can use the code below to recreate it:

**main.m** *0.23.1 - 0.62.0 from [Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.23.1&to=0.62.0-rc.2)*

```
/**
* Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
*
* This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
* LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
*/

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
  }
}
```

I really hope this helps someone out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue trying to archive a Mac Catalyst app (Swift 5 / Xcode 11.5), which up until attempting to archive was working fine and able to run / build successfully through `My Mac`.

Never was quite able to get to the root cause of why this ended up fixing it, but moving all of my root level project files (including `AppDelegate.swift`) into a group resolved the issue and allowed me to archive successfully

Before:

```
Project.xcodeproj
|--- Project
    |--- AppDelegate.swift
    |--- SceneDelegate.swift
    |--- Assets.xcassets
    |--- ViewControllers
        |--- ViewController.swift
```

After:

```
Project.xcodeproj
|--- Project
    |--- AppDelegate
        |--- AppDelegate.swift
        |--- SceneDelegate.swift
        |--- Assets.xcassets
    |--- ViewControllers
        |--- ViewController.swift
```